# How do I move the output of the blazer component to another location?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, blazer

Good afternoon, I recently switched from desktop development to asp.net core and so far everything is working out, but there is a question that I can't find the answer to anywhere.

- In general, the whole point is that there is a menu, and when the user selects one of the tabs, the Html code must be inserted in the right place. There is no problem to implement this by sending a request to the server and refreshing the page, but as for me, it is visually terrible.

  ```
  <section>
     <h3>Settings</h3>
       <p style="font-size:13px">General settings....etc</p>
        <footer>
            <ul>
            <li><component type="typeof(Component)" render-mode=ServerPrerendered/></li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
   </section>
  ```
- As you can see from this HTML, my button is located in the menu bar, respectively, it inserts the new HTML code there as well.
- Hence the question: is it possible to insert a component in one place of the code, and output its result in another?

Comment: Could you pls share how is your component like?

Comment: hi, I have already solved this issue on my own.It turned out that it was necessary, as usual, just to turn on the brain and ingenuity)